# Git squash from 1 commit to another commit id

Tags: git

I would like to squash all commits between 2 commit id's. Commit id `08f68388387e81aaff8e8cdfa619b6c23adef39d` is the first commit I made on the branch, and I would like to squash all commits till and including `d3ccda596adf33f38a6ad3f9bdf63a43713b6343` which is like the 23rd commit on the branch (of 30).

Comment: I usually do this with an interactive rebase like this: `git rebase -i HEAD~30`. Then replace the word pick in front of all commits with the word `fixup`. This will squash the commit into the previous commit while retaining only the commit message of the first commit

Comment: or `git rebase -i --root`, given that you want to start playing with revisions from the very first one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+combine+multiple+commits